# Wordpress/PHP: Problemas em manter variável $_SESSION ao mudar de página

Tags: php, session

Eu tenho o código abaixo no mesmo arquivo:

```
add_action( 'init', 'iniciaSessao', 1 );
function iniciaSessao() {
    if(!session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function info() {
$_SESSION['nome'] = 'meu nome';
}

info();
//session_regenerate_id(true);
wp_redirect($minhaUrl);
exit();
```

Ao ir na homepage do site (para onde está redirecionando) e usar `print_r($_SESSION['nome']);` não aparece a informação setada.

OBS: aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro ao descomentar o `session_regenerate`:

> session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que o redirecionamento levava para outro domínio (localhost para o ip do localhost) fazendo o wp acreditar que era outro domínio e limpar a sessão e cookies.